# Where do our grammar rules come from?

Tags: discussion, editing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [American English spelling vs British English spelling?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3993/american-english-spelling-vs-british-english-spelling)

Until now I haven't thought about this, as it seemed self-explanatory. But [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65711/what-can-be-done-with-artefact-clothes) question has raised the idea and question. How do we grammatically judge our questions? Based upon American Standards? NATO? Is there some International Grammar Association that the world as a whole uses to do this sort of thing?

Comment: Random fun reading about [artefact vs artifact](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-art1.htm)!